# Capture build parameters as html report in Jenkins

Tags: html, xml, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

As part of release management process, there can exist parallel releases targeting to overlap on environments.

Whats the best way to capture build parameters in Jenkins and add to a custom HTML report.

Like i want to see the following in the report ... 
1. Build parameters used in build#XXX of build_job_releaseYYY 
2. Sort the tabular report of build parameters to see how many releases have gone through Test1 environment etc

The approach i was thinking ...

1. Create an xml node for every set of build parameter ..
2. Some how keep adding these nodes to an xml - buildReport.xml
3. Generate an html report BuildReport.xml from the buildReport.xml to display a table of the  node
4. The html report should be sortable.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [simple parameterized build report](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Simple+Parameterized+Builds+Report+plugin) which may do what you want as it list the build parameters used in individual builds

[image]

This report is available of the job page as a link

Comment: This report is not fully useful because, the report is available in the job which is parameterized but not in the upstream job from where the artifacts are built and copied to the deploy job. Also this plugin only creates the chart based on build parameters and not variables defined in the build. So it still does not solve my scenario.